# Should a Git push be uploading files/directories?

Tags: git

I am coming off of a old-fashioned FTP workflow and am having trouble getting a development → staging → production Git process working. I am able to connect to both my staging and production servers via ssh/git.

I created an empty repository on the staging server and attempted to push my local dev repository. This appeared to work. However, the only file that seemed to upload was a big 2+GB file in the .git folder. None of my directories will upload. Is that the way this works or am I doing something wrong? I cannot figure out how to take my local project and push it up to a server the way I am used to doing it in FTP.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't upload empty directories.

Comment: some remarks: a) when you expect files to be created by git (i.e. you do not work on a `bare` clone) you should be pulling from that location, not pushing to that location from somewhere else. b) if your `.git` folder is 2+GB big, it is likely that you are using git in manner that will not make you happy. there are legitimate git repos of that size, but oftentimes it indicates that someone is abusing git and everybody will be unhappy.

Comment: Note that git is not meant as a deployment tool. You might want to consider using a dedicated deployment tool instead of git.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Codeschool's interactive lesson for github.

http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

It explains most of the stuff to get your started

Comment: @mnagel - meant to say that 2+GB includes media kits/large PSD's and things like that

Comment: There shouldn't a problem with large files..it will only take a little longer to upload.
You need to add every file that you want to push, you can add the files using `git add *`. `git status` will return a list of files currently added.

once you've added the files you must make a commit. only then can you push your changes to the server

Answer (score 1):

A standard git push won't actually update the working copy of the repository you're pushing to -- your changes are all there, waiting for you update your working copy manually.  This is for safety, in case you're working in your working copy :).  Really, `git push` is the opposite of `git fetch`, not of `git pull` -- consider that `git fetch` also doesn't update your working copy.

You can set up a hook to update your working copy after a push, if that's what you want.

Comment: @mnagel - if i'm deploying a site that was created locally and want to push the whole thing to a server, I don't understand how I'm expected to pull from it instead of push to? It seems like chicken before the egg?

Comment: You'll need to put something in your post-receive (or post-update) hook to populate your working copy.  For my repos, that involves exporting it somewhere else then building it.

Answer (score 0):

Git stores the entire commit tree in large binary blob files ('packs') which you are seeing. By default the server will only store the 'bare' repository so the files aren't actually checked out, and only the compressed pack data is there in the .git directory. You would have to have some post-commit scripts on the server if you want to keep a checked out and update-to-date version of the latest commit somewhere.

Comment: is it common to deploy a site with FTP, and then create the git repo on the production server and use Git for any changes from  that point on?